# LiveData not triggering twice in case of network request failing

Tags: android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

My `LiveData` object is called twice when my httprequest is succefull, but in case of an error, it's only called once, causing the UI to display an empty list since my `Error` verification was skipped since there was no alert fired.

My repository code

```
private LiveData<List<Card>> getCards() {
    return cardsDao.getCards();
}

// Network request, that deals with the success or error of the request

public LiveData<DataWrapper<List<Card>>> loadCards() {
    AtomicReference<LiveData<DataWrapper<List<Card>>>> atomicWrapper = new AtomicReference<>();
    if (getCards().getValue() == null) {
        webService.getCards(result -> {
            CardResponse res = (CardResponse) result;
            List<Card> cardList = res.getCardsList();
            getInsertAsyncTask.execute(cardList.toArray(new Card[cardList.size()]));
        }, error -> {
            atomicWrapper.set(asLiveData(null, error.getMessage()));
        }, TAG);
    }
    atomicWrapper.set(asLiveData(getCards(),null));
    return atomicWrapper.get();
}
```

My BaseRepository code

```
LiveData<DataWrapper<List<T>>> asLiveData(LiveData<List<T>> dataSource, String error) {
    MediatorLiveData<DataWrapper<List<T>>> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(dataSource, data -> mediatorLiveData.setValue(new DataWrapper<>(data, error)));
    return mediatorLiveData;
}
```

My Fragment code

```
private void subscribeToCards() {
    mViewModel.getCards().observe(this, listDataWrapper -> {
        if( listDataWrapper == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if( listDataWrapper.error != null) {
            // Show error on UI
            dismissProgress();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error - " + listDataWrapper.error);
            showError(getString(R.string.cards_error_get_list_message));
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new DialogMessageEvent(getString(R.string.cards_error_get_list_title),
                getString(R.string.cards_error_get_list_message), getString(R.string.cards_error_get_list_button)));
        }

        if( listDataWrapper.data != null ) {
            // Update Ui
            refreshCardsList(listDataWrapper.data);
            cardsViewVisibility(true);
        }
    });
}
```

And finally, my ViewModel code

```
public LiveData<DataWrapper<List<Card>>> getCards(){
    return repository.loadCards();
}
```

To summarize, in case of failure, why does the `observer callback` only gets called once ? Because I've debug it, and in both ( succefull and failure ) cases, the method `asLiveData` is called TWICE, but it's only in the succefull attempt that the callback is called TWICE aswell, on failure the `observer callback` it's only called ONCE.

Edit: Added asynctask code

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
AsyncTask<T,Void,Void> getInsertAsyncTask = new AsyncTask<T, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(T... ts) {
        daoObject.insertObjects(Arrays.asList(ts));
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: What does getInsertAsyncTask look like?

Comment: @Chris Added to the post. It's seems to work fine, as I said, my succesfull case when I get a list of Cards works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get 2 callbacks for the success case and only 1 call for the error scenario looks to be to do with your repository setup.

When calling loadCards you first emit the state of the database with this call:

```
atomicWrapper.set(asLiveData(getCards(),null));
```

Your database will be queried at this point and the current values will trigger the mediatorLiveData.setValue. This will be the **first** emission.

```
mediatorLiveData.addSource(dataSource, data -> mediatorLiveData.setValue(new DataWrapper<>(data, error)));
```

At the same time you have triggered a call to you webservice, which if successful will trigger your asynctask to update the database.

```
webService.getCards(result -> {
    CardResponse res = (CardResponse) result;
    List<Card> cardList = res.getCardsList();
    getInsertAsyncTask.execute(cardList.toArray(new Card[cardList.size()]));
}, error -> {
    atomicWrapper.set(asLiveData(null, error.getMessage()));
}, TAG);
```

Once the insert command completes the MediatorLiveData will trigger it's setValue call again - it's listening to changes in the database so on the insertion it will receive a callback. This is the **second** emission in the success case.

In the error scenario you pass through ***null*** as the dataSource. Its surprising this doesn't crash as the addSource method marks the source parameter as *Non Null*. As it is null you don't get a callback and the mediatorLiveData.setValue won't be called. This means for an error scenario you only receive the first emission.

It may be simpler if you did something like the following:

- setup a listener on the database and emit your datavalue without the error when a database update occurs.
- on receiving an error you could then just emit the DataWrapper with an error

e.g. something like:

```
    private final AtomicBoolean isLoading = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final MediatorLiveData<DataWrapper<List<Card>>> mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();

    private MyRepository() {
        // requires a cardsDao
        // listen for DB changes and emit on callback
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(cardsDao.getCards(), data -> mediatorLiveData.setValue(new DataWrapper<>(data, null)));
    }

    public LiveData<DataWrapper<List<Card>>> cardsData() {
        return mediatorLiveData;
    }

    public void loadCards() {
        if (!isLoading.get()) {
            isLoading.set(true);
            webService.getCards(result -> {
                CardResponse res = (CardResponse) result;
                List<Card> cardList = res.getCardsList();
                // Trigger update in db
                getInsertAsyncTask.execute(cardList.toArray(new Card[cardList.size()]));
                isLoading.set(false);
            }, error -> {
                // Emit the error
                mediatorLiveData.setValue(new DataWrapper<>(null, error.getMessage()));
                isLoading.set(false);
            }, TAG);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep my implementation was incorrect.. In the error case I was creating yet another `Mediator` instance.. I tried to mimic how google does in their sample, but I screwed up somewhere along the line

Comment: In this example, is how you usually deal with these kind of implementations ? Thanks for your answer. Put me in the right track

Comment: One of the best places to look at examples is the architecture components repo:

Their repository pattern is the one Google seem to be pushing for.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/RepoRepository.kt

Comment: One of the authors has a few blog posts which may also be useful - think it has some references on the repository pattern.

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-beyond-the-viewmodel-reactive-patterns-using-transformations-and-mediatorlivedata-fda520ba00b7

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54

Comment: There is also the android-sunflower project which is the latest showcase from google with respect to the Architecture Components: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower

Comment: Yes that was the github link I was following. But I'm not Kotlin *fluent*